# InfluxDB query to PromQL

Tags: prometheus, promql

I need to translate InfluxDB query to PromQL, please help. These are the requests:
https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/diskio

> Calculate percent IO utilization per disk and host:
>
> `SELECT non_negative_derivative(last("io_time"),1ms) FROM "diskio" WHERE time > now() - 30m GROUP BY "host","name",time(60s)`
>
> Calculate average queue depth: iops_in_progress will give you an
> instantaneous value. This will give you the average between polling
> intervals.
>
> `SELECT non_negative_derivative(last("weighted_io_time"),1ms) from "diskio" WHERE time > now() - 30m GROUP BY "host","name",time(60s)`

Answer (score 0):

The following PromQL queries should work assuming [this conversion scheme is used for converting InfluxDB data to Prometheus data](https://victoriametrics.github.io/#how-to-send-data-from-influxdb-compatible-agents-such-as-telegraf):

```
max(rate(diskio_io_time[60s])/1000) by (host, name)
```

```
max(rate(diskio_weighted_io_time[60s])/1000) by (host, name)
```

The division by `1000` is needed in order to convert milliseconds to seconds for the corresponding time series - `diskio_io_time` and `diskio_weighted_io_time`.

Prometheus accepts time range for the query via `start` and `end` args passed to [/api/v1/query_range](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-queries) Prometheus querying API handler, so queries above have no filters on time.